# Error in kohana-3.0.6.2: Class controller_kohana does not exist

Tags: kohana-3

I have successfully installed kohana and when i run i go the following error.

what to do to solve this error.

**Class controller_kohana does not exist**

thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having a same error message, if you came out with a solution, please tell us how you did it. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to bother you with my previous comment, but this link http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=4256 on Kohana forum solved my problem. Take a look at "banks" answers. happy coding!

Comment: Any chance you could add your answer here?  This link no longer works.

Comment: @Caimen Sorry I am not coding with Kohana anymore. try to google a little bit

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `base_url` of `Kohana::init` in `application/bootstrap.php`.